# Difference of Alternating Series and a Convergent Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let

$ S= \sum_{k=1} ^{\infty} \space (-1) ^{k-1}  \frac{1}{k} \Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big )^k$  and $ \space T= \sum_{k=1} ^{\infty} \space  \frac{1}{k} \Big(\frac{1}{5}\Big )^k$.

Then Which of the following statements are true?

$(\text{A}) \space S-T=0 $

$(\text{B}) \space 5S-4T=0 $

$(\text{C}) \space 4S-5T=0 $

$(\text{A}) \space 16S-25T=0 $

Things i know..

I used leibniz test  for alternating series and found out that $S$ is convergent and I know
$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{u^r}r = -\ln(1-u)$$ So,  $T$ is also Convergent, But I don't know to which value does $S$ converges.

Please do help me solving this.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Looking at the expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ and/or $\ln(1-x)$ note that
$$S = \ln\left(1+\frac 14\right) = \ln\left(\frac54\right)$$ and $$T = -\ln\left(1-\frac15\right) = \ln\left(\frac54\right)$$
(I think sum should start from $k=1$ otherwise the first term is not defined.)